# Angular 4-5: Custom directive not work in *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have created a custom directive to allow only number value in a text box. Normally it's working fine but whenever I am trying to us inside the *ngFor it's not working at all.

Here **OnlyNumber** is custom directive.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, ChangeDetectorRef, Input, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: '[OnlyNumber]' 
})

export class OnlyNumberDirective {
  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private el: ElementRef, private ngControl: NgControl) { }

  @Input() OnlyNumber: boolean;

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {    
    let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;
    if (this.OnlyNumber) {
      if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+V
        (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode === 88 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
          // let it happen, don't do anything
          return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
  }
}
```

**Not Working Code**

```
<tbody id="quote_type1_tbody" *ngFor="let loTempQuoteProduct of this.moTempQuoteProductList"> 
     <tr>
         <td> 
            <input type="text" id="ListCost" maxlength="8" 
                class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Enter list cost"
                [ngModel]="TempProduct.Cost"
                (ngModelChange)="TempProduct.Cost = $event;" 
                OnlyNumber="true">
         </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Working Code - Out side the ngFor**

```
<input type="text" id="ListCost" maxlength="8" 
            class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Enter list cost"
            [ngModel]="TempProduct.Cost"
            (ngModelChange)="TempProduct.Cost = $event;" 
            OnlyNumber="true">
```

Your valuable time and answer will be appreciated.

Thanks in advice!!

Comment: post your directive.

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: What is the behavior, are you loosing the focus from the element ?

Comment: what do you mean by _not working_?

Comment: @fatemefazli, I have edit question with directive code

Comment: @PardeepJain, Not any console error.

Comment: @SunilSingh, on key press i want to prevent an event. Please refer edited question. I have added directive code here.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, if we are going to apply directive inside ngFor, it's not work. FYI: Outside the loop, it's working fine.

Comment: are both template snippets part of the same component? or are you using the directive in different components?

Comment: multiple tbodies are generated there.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, I have created directive as a different component.

Comment: @Jai, no. there is only single body generated.

Comment: In the for statement you are using the same model and ngChangeModel to all elements that creates.. try to use different values. like use the `loTempQuoteProduct`variable. check the same come without models [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xaqe8y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Write your directive logic in ngOnInit()

Comment: Hello @Dhibin, It will help if you write your answer in more detail. Can you please write down what is the benefit of writing logic in ngOnInit(). Also, It would be really grateful if you can attached some code to showcase benefits.  for more details visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer